# Hbase shell command

Tags: hbase

I have a little silly Hbase question,but stuck me long time.
when I login the Hbase shell issued the following command:

```
[jack@HOST117-20 bin]$ ./hbase shell
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 0.94.0, r1332822, Tue May  1 21:43:54 UTC 2012

hbase(main):001:0>scon mytable
```

I found I can not delete the commands,for example if I type wrong command "scon",then I can not use Backspace or Delete button to delete the command,I have to retype again.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have never had this issue, but I have only played with 0.90.  What OS are you using?

Comment: yes,very strange,I doubt maybe lack of plug-in

Answer (score 4):

You might be using secureCRT on windows. I had the same issue in this configuration. I switched to PuTTY and the issue disappeared. If you still want to use SecureCRT, I found a workaround - go to session configuration and use Terminal "Linux" in the emulation section, and now in HBase Shell, you can use Ctrl-backspace to do the "backspace" job.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and found that the issue could be reproduced even with the standard irb by typing the following command line (I found this command line by reading /usr/lib/hbase/bin/hbase).

```
$ java -cp \
    ~/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.6.5/jruby-complete-1.6.5.jar \
    org.jruby.Main /usr/bin/irb
```

Therefore, the root cause exists not in HBase shell but in JRuby, and further investigation revealed that the root cause exists in JLine used by JRuby 1.6.5.

First, I created ~/.jlinebindings.properties file and put "Rubout: backward-delete-char" there, hoping that backspace key would do "delete one character behind the cursor", but it did not work. Even worse, the existence of .jlinebindings.properties file cleared other key bindings (ex. bindings for arrow keys), so I removed .jlinebindings.properties. I tried adding the key binding settings to ~/.jline.rc and ~/.inputrc, but they did not work, either.

I checked out JLine2 source code to investigate further and found that the latest version of JLine2 does not support .jlinebindings.properties file. But, .jline.rc is supported. So, I compiled the latest JLIne2 source code, put the key binding to .jline.rc file and specified the JLine2 library (target/jline-2.10-SNAPSHOT.jar) as the first element of classpath, but it did not work. With the newly built JLine2 library, JRuby 1.6.5 threw IncompatibleClassChangeError. This means that JLine2 has changed its API and broken backward compatibility.

Next, I checked out JRuby source code and compiled it as follows.

```
# JRuby compilation requires ant
$ yum install ant

# Without this, compilation fails.
$ yum install ant-apache-regexp

$ git clone https://github.com/jruby/jruby.git

# Check the latest version
$ git tag

$ git checkout 1.7.1
$ mvn install
```

With the new JRuby binary, I invoked the command line again.

```
$ java -cp \
    ~/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.7.1/jruby-complete-1.7.1.jar \
    org.jruby.Main /usr/bin/irb
```

But, it raised SyntaxError.

```
SyntaxError: file:/home/admin/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.7.1/jruby-complete-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/irb/lc/ja/encoding_aliases.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected kEND

end
  ^
         eval at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1066
    real_load at jar:file:/home/admin/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.7.1/jruby-complete-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/irb/locale.rb:134
         load at jar:file:/home/admin/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.7.1/jruby-complete-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/irb/locale.rb:110
   initialize at jar:file:/home/admin/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.7.1/jruby-complete-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/irb/locale.rb:32
  init_config at jar:file:/home/admin/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.7.1/jruby-complete-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/irb/init.rb:114
        setup at jar:file:/home/admin/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.7.1/jruby-complete-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/irb/init.rb:16
        start at jar:file:/home/admin/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.7.1/jruby-complete-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/irb.rb:53
       (root) at /usr/bin/irb:13
```

There must be something wrong in encoding_aliases.rb (or the new JRuby has made some changes breaking backward-compatibility) but I did not have mind to investigate it and so added LANG=C as a workaround.

```
$ LANG=C java -cp \
    ~/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.7.1/jruby-complete-1.7.1.jar \
    org.jruby.Main /usr/bin/irb
```

This successfully invoked irb, and I could confirm that the backspace works as expected. maven/jruby-core/pom.xml says that the version of JLIne referred to by JRuby 1.7.1 is 2.7.

As a final step, I tried to let HBase shell use the new JRuby by doing the following.

```
$ cd /usr/lib/hbase/lib
$ mv jruby-complete-1.6.5.jar{,.backup}
$ cp ~/.m2/repository/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.7.1/jruby-complete-1.7.1.jar .
$ hbase shell
```

But, HBase shell did not start. Instead, error messages below were emitted.

```
include_class is deprecated. Use java_import.
include_class is deprecated. Use java_import.
include_class is deprecated. Use java_import.
12/12/28 18:03:12 WARN conf.Configuration: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
NoMethodError: undefined method `getTerminal' for Java::Jline::Terminal:Module
  refresh_width at /usr/lib/hbase/bin/../bin/../lib/ruby/shell/formatter.rb:34
     initialize at /usr/lib/hbase/bin/../bin/../lib/ruby/shell/formatter.rb:47
         (root) at /usr/lib/hbase/bin/../bin/hirb.rb:108
```

These error messages indicate that replacing jruby-complete-*.jar under /usr/lib/hbase/lib does not solve the issue.

So, I gave up and concluded that there was no simple workaround against the issue. My final conclusion is that we have to wait for HBase experts to update HBase shell implementation with new JRuby.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exam same problem. I use SecureCRT in xterm mode in a Win 7 box to SSH to a CentOS 6.3 Linux server.

I installed hbase and stuff, then I found out that both my backspace and delete keys are deleting rightward. So, @Jack , I guess your backspace wasn't broken, it's just that it's functioning as another delete key, rather than its normal behavior(which is deleting leftward).

I found a solution: use Ctrl + Backspace to left-delete. It works like a charm for me. So if you haven't figured out a fix in the past 2 years, you should try this ;)

Btw, although I found this workaround, I still don't know why it is happening. If anyone knows the reason of this problem ( irb's bug or wrong setting of SecureCRT ? ) , please tell me. Thanks!